# How to see the users has access to which projects in the Azure DevOps Organization?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

[image]

I'm unable to achieve below functinality:

How to see the users has access to which projects in the Azure DevOps Organization?

Is only Azure DevOps Organization Admin/Owner can see it or any other member can see this.

If any other member can see, what access that member should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check which users have which project access level:

Click on Organization settings:

[image]

Then Click On users the click on user and then manage user like below:

[image]

[image]

For my account(user), I have these permission through which i am able to see 2 users:

[image]